# Is it possible to store data of an application in the Apple Account of the user?

Tags: ios, swift, server

My application lets a user to do a thing 10 times

But when this user did this thing 10 times, he cannot do this thing anymore for one year.
So my application needs to know how many times the user do this thing.
I cannot store this number of times in the NSUserDefaults because when the user delete the application or if he changes his phone, this amount of times returns to 0.

So my question is : Is it possible to store this amount of times directly in his Apple Account related to my application or somewhere/something like that ?

Or do I need a server to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in **KeyChain**. It would stay even if the user deletes the app.

Sample code available here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/GenericKeychain.zip

Answer (score 0):

I would try [CloudKit](http://nshipster.com/cloudkit/). You can associate data with a user's iCloud account. NB: this account can differ from the AppStore account used to download your app.

Comment: Is the user can deletes the informations relatives to my application ? And the variable which contains the number of times ?